# How to enable MS Word document editing, when the document is protected to use form fields?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document in which I need to use form fields (populating list entries through VBA). Before handing over the Word document to the end user I have to restrict editing on form fields (Developer - Restrict Editing). But it is restricting the whole document for editing and the user cannot even edit remaining fields in the document.

I have tried stop protecting whole document but that exposes form fields to the user. Also drop-downs don't work on form fields if I don't protect the document.

Comment: Which version of Word is involved? Have you researched using content controls, instead, which can be "locked" so that the user can't change them - no forms protection involved at all? Beyond that, research use of *section breaks* in a document to enable protecting some content, but not other. Note also, please, that this is in essence an ***end-user*** issue, even though code is being used to write information to the Word document. VBA can only "mimic" what's available to the user - the solution is to understand what's available in Word, first.

Comment: Yes, content control has protection feature. And now I have pasted vba code in contentControlOnExit event to run it . Thanks for the suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re:

> it is restricting the whole document for editing and the user cannot even edit remaining fields in the document

If those 'other fields' are formfields and you use 'filling in forms' editing restrictions, the editing restrictions do not prevent access to the 'other fields'. And if some other content not using formfields requires user access, you can insert a Section break before & after that content, then leave that Section unprotected when applying the 'filling in forms' editing restrictions.

The same approach works with content controls also.

Note, however, you should not use formfields and content controls in the same document. They weren't designed for use that way and trying to do so is a known source of problems.

Comment: Section break is not working as it stops protecting form fields also and as a result, its drop down feature stops working. I used content controls and the tool is working fine now. Thanks for your time!

Comment: As I'd have thought was plain from the answer I posted, you'd *only* use the Section break(s) where you want the users to be able to do free text entry/editing, *not* where there are formfields/content controls. You can have however many Section breaks you need to achieve the desired granularity.